# Laravel Connection could not be established with host smtp.office365.com

Tags: laravel

for outlook, it neither works in localhost nor in production server.
but for testing purpose, I used Gmail in localhost and it worked.

but again in production, it didn't work.

```
MAIL_DRIVER smtp
MAIL_HOST smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT 587, 
MAIL_USERNAME ********, 
MAIL_PASSWORD ********, 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION tsl
```

Comment: please post the php code

Comment: MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= //your username
MAIL_PASSWORD= //your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: it is working in localhost.

Answer (score 5):

Just set up correct Configuration:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME= //your username
MAIL_PASSWORD= //your password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

After `.env` edit must be clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: that is what i am using. for some stack overflow formatted problem i posted like that

Comment: @Arora have you cleared cache ? run this command in your command prompt `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @Arora change `MAIL_ENCRYPTION tsl`  to `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls`

Comment: Sorry. MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=******
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Comment: Thanks. now it worked in my local server... let me check in production and inform...

Comment: ran command php artisan config:cache in production. error# connection timed out

Comment: Hello, i have the same issue, it works properly on local but not in production.

Comment: The same form me @pCyril, any issue?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, change port 587 to 25 work fine.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fHow-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4#option-2-send-mail-directly-from-your-printer-or-application-to-office-365-direct-send)

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'sendmail'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'localhost'),
```

it works.